# Forward email to Gmail in Android app but not desktop

Tags: email, gmail, android, apple-mail

I have two email accounts - university and Gmail. I access them using Apple Mail as two separate accounts. I would like both accounts to be viewable in the Gmail app on my Android phone.

Is there a way to forward university email to Gmail so that I can have this whilst avoiding getting university emails through twice in Apple Mail?

Comment: Just setup Google Mail to download the emails in both accounts.

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm not familiar with Apple Mail, you can use the "Accounts/Import" feature to forward emails that you own from one account to your gmail account and make it to where if you've read one of the emails in one account, both accounts will mark the email as read. I am also a student and this feature has been invaluable to me.

### Instructions

Open up Gmail. Click on the gear icon in the top right. It brings up a dropdown menu. Click settings in the dropdown menu. Click the "Accounts/Import" tab. Under the "Send mail as:" sub-heading, click "Add another email address you own." From there, it will give you step by step instructions. Good luck!